# Can't create new user in ejabberd using ejabberdctl

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabberd 16.08 in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I started ejabberd successfully. after open browser I typed URL: http://localhost:5280/admin, I entered a username (full JABBER ID) and password (installation password) but it's not logged in.

Then in my terminal, I register new user

```
sudo ./ejabberdctl register admin localhost password
```

a user has not created, an error came.

```
{error, access_rules_unauthorized}
```

Please give me some solution to fix this error. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ejabberd user registration command fails with {error,access\_rules\_unauthorized}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810951/ejabberd-user-registration-command-fails-with-error-access-rules-unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

Try 16.06 from downloads archive https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/ It solved my issue on Centos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default admin and password to get the access of web portal.
Username: admin@yourpcname
Password:admin