# Ejabberd user registration command fails with {error,access_rules_unauthorized}

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-saas

I've been trying to set up an XMPP server using ejabberd on windows. every time I try to register a user in ejabberd with this command:

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost admin
```

it gives me this error:

`{error,access_rules_unauthorized}`

I've installed the ejabberd using its binary installer and according to "install.log" file, the installer also fails to create a user due to the same error.

**Part of the log file:**

```
E:\Program Files\ejabberd-16.08\bin>bash ejabberdctl register "admin" "localhost" "admin" 
{error,access_rules_unauthorized}
```

**ejabberd.yml config file:**

```
access_rules:
  register:
    - allow
```

I've gone even to the 100th search of the google, but found nothing similiar yet. So any help on how to fix this is strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is an error in ejabberd 16.08 and has been fixed in the git master.

For the corresponding issue, see https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1231.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in windows, is it solved in 16.08 for windows?

Comment: this may help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206886/cant-login-to-ejabberd-admin-panel

Answer (score 3):

Try version 16.06 instead of 16.08 from downloads archive https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/ It solved my issue on Centos.

Comment: Installing 16.06 instead of 16.08 fixed the issue on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Version [16.06](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/) work for me in windows10, before installation keep firewall off.