# Can't login to ejabberd admin panel

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I downloaded ejabberd for Windows, and during the setup process created the admin name and password. I'm attempting to access the admin control panel (localhost:5280/admin), and am attempting to login with the username (admin@MyServer) and password, but each time it just asks me to log in again. The server is running too, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ejabberd 16.09 will be released shortly and will include that fix.
>   [Ref: Here.](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1231)

for now start ejabberd with this command `ejabberdctl live` and see the log when you try to login.

if it says `in-existed account` than you have to download xmpp client software from [here.](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.html)

After Installing this creat the admin account from this client after you have does this you will be successful is logging in the admin control.

### Settings for Pidgin:

**Add:**

```
 1. Protocol : xmpp
 2. Username : admin
 3. Domain : MyServer
 4. Password : asyouwant
```

**Advance:**

```
1. Connect Server : localhost
```

donot forget to check the `create this account on the server` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I used `admin@nabin-pc` instead of `admin@NABIN-PC` and got logged in successfully.